# vaadin 23.3.19 gradle plugin with conflicting jna and oshi dependency

Tags: gradle, vaadin

I'm applying the vaadin 23.3.19 gradle plugin and run the `vaadinBuildFrontend` task.
It fails because of conflicting libraries `com.github.oshi` and `net.java.dev.jna`. The method `Memory.close()` does not exist.

The application to build itself has `vaadin`, `oshi` and `jna` on the classpath.
But I assume that the plugin itself should have its isolated classpath and the proper libraries on board. If so, why does it fail?

Or does it work with the above libraries provided by the application dependencies?
For that case I have already added a dependency resolution for the case that the conflicts are coming from the application dependendecises, still this will not fix it.

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.oshi') {
                details.useVersion '6.4.1'
                details.because('conflicting version with jna/vaadin')
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'net.java.dev.jna') {
                details.useVersion '5.13.0'
                details.because('conflicting version with jna/vaadin')
            }
        }
    }
```

```
      Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.jna.Memory.close()'
                at oshi.util.platform.mac.SysctlUtil.sysctl(SysctlUtil.java:53)
                at oshi.util.platform.mac.SysctlUtil.sysctl(SysctlUtil.java:40)
                at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(MacCentralProcessor.java:119)
                at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:65)
                at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacCentralProcessor.<init>(MacCentralProcessor.java:47)
                at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(MacHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:42)
                at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:61)
                at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:48)
                at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.MachineId.getComputerId(MachineId.java:34)
                at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.MachineId.get(MachineId.java:19)
                at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker.checkLicense(LicenseChecker.java:226)
                at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker.checkLicense(LicenseChecker.java:129)
                at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker.checkLicense(LicenseChecker.java:104)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.CvdlProducts.includeInFallbackBundle(CvdlProducts.java:93)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports.lambda$filter$0(TaskUpdateImports.java:486)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
                at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
                at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports$UpdateFallBackImportsFile.getModules(TaskUpdateImports.java:278)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.collectModules(AbstractUpdateImports.java:314)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.run(AbstractUpdateImports.java:128)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports.execute(TaskUpdateImports.java:388)
                at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342)
                at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runNodeUpdater(BuildFrontendUtil.java:343)
                at com.vaadin.gradle.VaadinBuildFrontendTask.vaadinBuildFrontend(VaadinBuildFrontendTask.kt:71)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:248)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
                at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
                at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin 23.3.19 uses `license-checker` 1.12.3, which uses `oshi-core` 6.4.1 and `jna`/`jna-platform` 5.13.0.

Which versions of oshi and jna does your app define (or use as a transitive deps)?

To check if the application level deps are isolated or not, I tried running https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-gradle/tree/v23 starter project with 23.3.19 and defined a random jna version

```
implementation "net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.10.0"
```

then by running

```
./gradlew clean build -Pvaadin.productionMode --info
```

I've got a successful build with the following lines in logs:

```
Passing this classpath to NodeTasks.Builder: [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar, vaadin-core-23.3.19.jar, slf4j-simple-1.7.36.jar, vaadin-dev-server-23.3.16.jar, **license-checker-1.12.3.jar, oshi-core-6.4.1.jar, jna-platform-5.13.0.jar, jna-5.13.0.jar**, ...]
```

So, the plugin still uses the versions defined in it's configuration, not the ones from app.

This is just an assumption, but looks like your project somehow uses different versions of Vaadin gradle plugin and Vaadin platform (for instance beta version of 23.3), so I would check it first. This might give these kind of errors.

Could you please run with `--info` and give the versions logged?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same versions.

Comment: I'm also running the buildEnvironment task also showing the same oshi, jna and license-checker versions.
However, it's a bit confusing that event though I'm using  com.vaadin:com.vaadin.gradle.plugin:23.3.19, internally I see com.vaadin:flow-plugin-base:23.3.16 as a dependency of the plugin.

Comment: Having 23.3.16 version is fine, because Vaadin Gradle plugin as well as Vaadin platform 23.3.19 are based on Vaadin Flow and flow-plugin-base version 23.3.16, see Flow version in RN https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/23.3.19.

Comment: `Memory::close` method is available in JNA in versions >=5.12.0. So somehow the JNA older than 5.12.0 gets used during the build.

Comment: If possible, could you please give us a minimal reproducible example and attach it to an issue in Flow https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new/choose ? I cannot reproduce it with our starter, which obviously has a quite basic configuration which works.

Comment: I can already give you more information as I have a fix for now. The application is applying the spring-boot plugin (2.7.3) and this one comes with JNA 5.7.
So I have added the spring boot plugin to the starter as well. And it still works. Gradle upgrades the spring boot JNA version from 5.7 to 5.13

But I think the behaviour with the classloading issue comes with the multi-module build that I have. Here I see the issue that that dependency upgrade does not happen and for this reason the build fails.
I have been able to fix that with a buildscript resolutionStrategy forcing the JNA lib

Comment: `
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
          force 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.13.0'
          force 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0'
       }
    }
}
`